# How to call and execute a shell script using PuTTY from VBA macro

Tags: vba, putty

I am trying to write a VBA macro which will login using PuTTY and execute commands. The below code has been used.

```
Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
    UserName = "user name"
    Passwrd = "password"
    pc1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY/putty.exe -ssh " & UserName & "@ip address -pw " & Passwrd
    pc2 = "putty.exe -m ""C:\Temp\emu.sh"""
    TaskID = Shell(pc1, 1)
    TaskID = Shell(pc2, 1)

End Sub
```

Script throws an error saying

> 'Run-time error '53' - File not found'.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to quote the path to PuTTY, as it contains spaces.
- Also you execute `putty.exe` twice. Instead you have to pass all those parameters to a single instance of `putty.exe`

```
pc1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"" " & _
    "-ssh " & UserName & "@ip address -pw " & Passwrd & " -m ""C:\Temp\emu.sh"""
TaskID = Shell(pc1, 1)
```

And you should consider using [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) instead of `putty.exe`, what is a PuTTY tool intended to automation. PuTTY is GUI application intended for an interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

File paths with spaces need to be quoted:

```
Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
    UserName = "user name"
    Passwrd = "password"
    pc1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"" -ssh " & _
           UserName & "@ip address -pw " & Passwrd
    pc2 = "putty.exe -m ""C:\Temp\emu.sh"""
    TaskID = Shell(pc1, 1)
    TaskID = Shell(pc2, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, what is "& _" ? What is "-pw"?  I do not understand for which reason these are applied in code? May I request you to explain little bit on these doubts?